# I have trouble animating my element with html and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, onclick

I am trying to animate my input labels to move up after click the way it works is after clicking on input a class which contains the animation I want is assigned to the label, but it is not working.

```js
let $ = document
let usernameInputLabel = $.querySelector(".username-input-label")
let usernameInput = $.querySelector(".username-input")

let isFocused = false

function focusAnimation() {
  if (isFocused) {
    usernameInputLabel.classList.remove(".username-focus-label-animation")
    usernameInputLabel.classList.add(".username-blur-label-animation")
    isFocused = false
  } else {
    usernameInputLabel.classList.add(".username-focus-label-animation")
    usernameInputLabel.classList.remove(".username-blur-label-animation")
    isFocused = true
  }
}
usernameInput.addEventListener("click", focusAnimation)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: urbanist;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #496d8d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  width: 130%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #082c4c;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #224f3900;
  padding: 0.2rem 0 0.2rem 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: relative;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.group {
  width: 60%;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(0, 2.1rem);
  user-select: none;
  color: #ddd;
}

.username-focus-label-animation {
  animation: usenramefocusLabelAnimation 700ms forwards;
}

@keyframes usenramefocusLabelAnimation {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 2.1rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0.1rem);
  }
}

.username-blur-label-animation {
  animation: usenrameBlurLabelAnimation 700ms forwards;
}

@keyframes usenrameBlurLabelAnimation {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0.1rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 2.1rem);
  }
}

button:not(.show-password) {
  background-color: #082c4c;
  scale: 1.8;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 2px #082c4c70, 0 2px 10px -1px #0f497b inset;
  transition: 500ms;
}

button:not(.show-password):hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px #082c4c70, 0 2px 10px -1px #0f497b inset;
  background-color: #07345b;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px #082c4c90, 0 15px 10px #082c4c90, 0 25px 10px #082c4c90;
}

.login-container {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  background-color: #1d5582;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px 1px #082c4c inset
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <p class="heading">sign in to your account</p>
  <form>
    <div class="username-group group">
      <label class="username-input-label " for="username-input">User name</label>
      <input class="username-input" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="password-group group">
      <label class="password-input-label" for="password-input">password</label>
      <input class="password-input" type="text">
      <!-- <button class="show-password">show password</button>    -->
    </div>
    <div class="confirm-password-group group">
      <label class="confirm-password-input-label" for="confirm-password-input">confirm password</label>
      <input class="confirm-password-input"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="email-group group">
      <label class="email-input-label" for="email-input">email adress</label>
      <input class="email-input"></input>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button class="sign-up">sign up</button>
</div>
```

The animation is written correctly and the function seems to work fine. I can't see what is the problem

Comment: A small misake in your Javascript: Remove the `.` from the classnames that you either add or remove from the various elements. IE `usernameInputLabel.classList.add(".username-focus-label-animation")` should be `usernameInputLabel.classList.add("username-focus-label-animation")`

Comment: Your use of `for` attribute is wrong. `for` should point to the input ID. Also, you don't need to use `for` or `id` at all if you wrap `<input>` in `<label>`.

Comment: there is also no `</input>` tag in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pure HTML and CSS in order to animate the input labels:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.login-container {

  max-width: 20rem;

  h2 {
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }

  & form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  & label {
    position: relative;
    
    & span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0.5rem;
      top: 0.5rem;
      transform-origin: left;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  }
  
  & input {
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #082c4c;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   width: 100%;
   
   &:not(:placeholder-shown),
   &:focus {
     &~span {
       translate: 0px -1.3rem;
       scale: 0.8;
     }
   }
   &:focus {
     outline: none;
     border-bottom-color: #0bf;
   }
   &:invalid {
     border-bottom-color: #f00;
   }
  }
  
  & button {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">

  <h2>Sign in to your account</h2>

  <form action="/api/signin">
    <label><input type="text" name="username" placeholder=""><span>Username</span></label>
    <label><input type="password" name="password1" placeholder=""><span>Password</span></label>
    <label><input type="password" name="password2" placeholder=""><span>Confirm password</span></label>
    <label><input type="email" name="email" placeholder=""><span>Email</span></label>
    <button>Sign in</button>
  </form>
  
</div>
```